# Facebook authentication signup more information about client

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, yii2

How can i get user name and surname from facebook authentication. I do login with facebook and i want to do signup. I need Name, Surname and birthday from user. I read about this but cant find concrete information.

my controller is here:

```
public function oAuthSuccess($client) {
        // get user data from client
        $userAttributes = $client->getUserAttributes();

        $user = User::find()->where(['Email' => $userAttributes['email']])->one();
        if (!$user) {
            $model = new \frontend\modules\settings\models\ProfileForm();
            $model->Name = $userAttributes['name'];
            $model->Email = $userAttributes['email'];
            if ($model->saveFacebookClient()) {
                Yii::$app->user->login($model);
            }
            return $this->redirect('index.php?r=content/news');
        }
        Yii::$app->user->login($user);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the API call:

```
/me?fields=first_name,last_name,birthday
```

Of course you need to authorize the user with the `user_birthday` permission. Information about the login process in general can be found in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login

I suggest using the JavaScript SDK for login, here´s one tutorial: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

If you really want to login with PHP, here are more links:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-php-sdk-5-tutorial/

Comment: so what should i do to authorize the user with the user_birthday permission?

Comment: and where in conreooller?

Comment: i cant see anywhere good example how to get this data from user

Comment: i added some relevant links about login.

Comment: sorry, but stackoverflow is not a place to get work done for free, you have to do some research, programming and testing on your own first (that´s how you learn to program). we are happy to help when you got stuck, but you have to present what you have done so far. show us your login code.

Comment: btw, if you take a look at the links in my answer, there IS an example already. with all the code you need. i just added some more links too.

Comment: i still cant find one clear code how to take permissions and ho take birthday for example on php

Comment: the last 2 links offer very clear code for login including permissions. birthday: $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=first_name,last_name,birthday');

Comment: oh, my bad. the last link was older, i replaced it with a newer one for the php sdk 5: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-php-sdk-5-tutorial/

Comment: i should do it in controller or create model?

Comment: i dont want to install this sdk its possible to only draw this data without installing this sdk? I do login without this and i want to do registration without this it is possible?

Comment: you don´t need to use the php sdk, you can also do api calls with curl. here´s another link for you that includes some basic curl calls to the graph api: http://www.devils-heaven.com/extended-page-access-tokens-curl/